# Stop spans wrapping inside div

Tags: css, flexbox

In the following pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeRZee when you make the browser narrow so the yellow div does not fit, instead of it wrapping down to the next line, id like the yellow span to stay where it is and it's container to show horizontal scroll bar so you can scroll to the right to see the remainder of the yellow span.

I can't use `display: inline-block` for the blue and yellow spans as I am already using `display: flex` as I need it for their contents.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item1 {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item2 {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='item1'>
    I'm using flex here so I can center vertically
  </span>
  <span class='item2'>
    I'm using flex here so I can center vertically
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine flex and inline, simply use

```
display: inline-flex;
```

for both your items.

Also, add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

To your container's CSS to prevent the content from wrapping if the container's size (which is `width: 100%;` is exceeded.

This solution is close to your current implementation. Another possible way would be to also use flexbox for your container.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realise I could combine both. That sorted it. Apologies for not following the SO rules properly there.